# Initializing an n-qubit quantum circuit with a size 2^n array?

Tags: qiskit

I have a 16 qubit quantum circuit initialized as such:

```
qc.initialize(initial_state, [*range(16)])
```

where `initial_state` is a size $2^{16}$ array with normalized predefined probability amplitudes. I have a list of numbers in the range of $0-2^{16}$. Each of these values are given an amplitude, and are plugged into their index (the number) in a size $2^{16}$ array filled with zeros. I need to put my quantum circuit in a superposition of all these states, where $|00000000000000000\rangle$ is zero,$|00000000000000001\rangle$ is 1, etc. Am I correctly initializing my quantum circuit?